# How to substract a specifiek text from a string with the function substring

Tags: c++

In order to substract a timestamp from my string i am using substring( pos,#char).

My code works partially. The problem that i have is consistency. 
I am retrieving a string from a textfile in the format "Name Time" , 
Example : "Don 00:12".

this string is extracted from the file into HighScoreInfo1.
Also from a different file i am extracting a string, which is the name part, into previous_name.

With this information i am trying to calculate the position where the substring has to start.

```
int test = HighScoreInfo1.size() - (previous_name.size()+1 );
```

i already took measures for the extra char which is a space, thats the +2. 
1 for the space and 1 to get to the position where he needs to start.

the timestamp, 00:00, is five characters long.

```
                int test = HighScoreInfo1.size() - (previous_name.size()+2 );
                TimeToBeat = HighScoreInfo1.substr(test, 5);
                TestFile << "Orginal string size " << ">>" << HighScoreInfo1.size() << " " << "size of name"<< ">>" <<previous_name.size()+2<<" "  << "Position "<< test << endl;
                TestFile << "Orginal string " << ">>"<<HighScoreInfo1 << " " << "Substring"<< ">>" <<TimeToBeat << endl;
```

this is my output with a long name:

```
   Orginal string size >>14            size of name>>10 Position >> 4
   Orginal string      >>Chrystel 00:09 Substring>>stel
```

Sidenote: you cant see it, but with the above example the **space** after "stel" is the fifth character.

This is my output with a short name:

```
   Orginal string size >>9         size of name>>5 Position>> 4
   Orginal string      >>Don 00:09 Substring    >>00:09
```

with the shorter name i get my timestamp perfectly.

How can make this works consistent.
I did not added the rest of my code because that part works. it is basically only the substring part that does not work consistent.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Since, the time has always a size of 5, you can simply `HighScoreInfo1.substr(HighScoreInfo1.size() - 5);` and just ignore whatever is before the time.

Comment: You could set a standard size, fill the name then fill the rest with some predefined chars that you know you need to ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calculating `test` correctly. It should just be 1 more than the size of the name, not the size of `HighScoreInfo1` minus that (that's the length of the timestamp, which you know is `5`). You only need to add `1`, not `2`, because positions are zero-based.

```
int test = previous_name.size() + 1;
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/NsxJMg)

It only works with the shorter name by coincidence, because the name happens to be 3 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

```
int test = HighScoreInfo1.size() - (previous_name.size()+2 );
```

This calculates the length of the time (which is always 5).

```
TimeToBeat = HighScoreInfo1.substr(test, 5);
```

This gets the characters 5-10. Always. Regardless of the length of the string.  Perhaps you meant to do this, which reads the last five bytes?

```
TimeToBeat = HighScoreInfo1.substr(HighScoreInfo1.size()-5);
```

Comment: this helped, thnks ... i geuss my thought process was in reverse on this